# Alert not triggered when images touch each other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection, konvajs

I am non-native English speaker and I am beginner of programming language. I understand that my explanation is not best but I am trying to explain better to people to understand what I am trying to do. So, please be patient with me and please not try to down vote (it hurt my feelings) instead of tell me why my explanation is bad. I appreciate your time to read this. Thank you.

I am working on canvas game called coin sorting game which is drag the coins to the correct piggy bank images. I am stuck with if condition right now. In the current state, alert will not trigger when specific image touch to other specific image. For example, when 1yen coin image touches with 1yen piggy bank image then trigger alert otherwise no event occur.

I thought adding images to if condition will set specific images but it did not work.

```
   if (haveIntersection(obj.getClientRect(), targetRect)&& (ichiYenImg === ichiYenpiggyImg)) {
  alert("Intersection");
    }
```

Can anyone give me an advice how to attempt this problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  container: 'container'
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

layer.on('dragmove', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var targetRect = e.target.getClientRect();
  layer.children.each(function(obj) {
    if (obj === target) {
      return;
    }
    if (haveIntersection(obj.getClientRect(), targetRect)&& (ichiYenImg === ichiYenpiggyImg)) {
      alert("Intersection");
        }
  });
});

function haveIntersection(r1, r2) {
  return !(
    r2.x > r1.x + r1.width/2 ||
    r2.x + r2.width/2 < r1.x ||
    r2.y > r1.y + r1.height/2 ||
    r2.y + r2.height/2 < r1.y
  );
}

// This will draw the image on the canvas.
function drawImage(source, konvaImage) {
  layer.add(konvaImage);
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = source;
  image.onload = function() {
    konvaImage.image(image);
    layer.draw();
  }
}


//1yen
var ichiYenImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: true
});
var sourceImg1 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane5.png";
drawImage(sourceImg1, ichiYenImg);


var goYenImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 120,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: true
});
var sourceImg2 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane7.png";
drawImage(sourceImg2, goYenImg);

//piggy bank 1yen
var ichiYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 300,
  y: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: false
});
var sourceImg7 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416628-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-96e8-e709ace70ec1.png";
drawImage(sourceImg7, ichiYenpiggyImg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.5/konva.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stage-parent">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have presented a clear case and a usable code sample. This is a well formulated question - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mainly good - the issue is with the comparison of the objects in the 'if' statement copied below, where your intention is to decide if the user is dragging the correct value coin to the piggy bank. Comparing JavaScript objects is valid, but it can lead to unpredictable results - a more reliable & robust approach is to be more explicit, set a known attribute value on each object and compare those values.

```
if (haveIntersection(obj.getClientRect(), targetRect)&& (ichiYenImg === ichiYenpiggyImg)) {
  alert("Intersection");
}
```

My answer in the code snippet is to modify the code to use the Konva 'name' variable to hold the coin and bank values. You can see I set them both to 1yen. Now in the dragMove() function I get the name attr from each of the objects being compared. When they match, we have a valid hit, and when no match the coin & bank combination are invalid.

I modified the code to put a red border around the bank when the correct coin is dragged.

See the Konva documentation for the name attr [here](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Shape.html#name__anchor).

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  container: 'container'
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

layer.on('dragmove', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var targetRect = e.target.getClientRect();
  layer.children.each(function(obj) {
    if (obj === target) {
      return;
    }

    // capture the result of the intersection test.
    var checkHit = haveIntersection(obj.getClientRect(), targetRect);

    // get the objects name attribute
    var nameDragged = e.target.attrs['name']; 
    var namePiggy = obj.attrs['name'];
    
    // decide if they match
    var checkNames = (nameDragged === namePiggy);

    // finally decide if we have a valid hit
    if (checkHit && checkNames) {
      // hit ok !
      obj.stroke('red');
      obj.strokeWidth(2)
    }
    else {
      // no hit or not matching name
      obj.stroke(false);
      obj.strokeWidth(0)
    }

  });
});

function haveIntersection(r1, r2) {
  return !(
    r2.x > r1.x + r1.width/2 ||
    r2.x + r2.width/2 < r1.x ||
    r2.y > r1.y + r1.height/2 ||
    r2.y + r2.height/2 < r1.y
  );
}

// This will draw the image on the canvas.
function drawImage(source, konvaImage) {
  layer.add(konvaImage);
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = source;
  image.onload = function() {
    konvaImage.image(image);
    layer.draw();
  }
}


//1yen
var ichiYenImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: true,
  name: '1yen'      // use the name attribute to indicate the coin value
});
var sourceImg1 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane5.png";
drawImage(sourceImg1, ichiYenImg);


var goYenImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 120,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: true
});
var sourceImg2 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane7.png";
drawImage(sourceImg2, goYenImg);

//piggy bank 1yen
var ichiYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 300,
  y: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: false,
  name: '1yen'   // use the name attribute to indicate the coin value
});
var sourceImg7 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416628-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-96e8-e709ace70ec1.png";
drawImage(sourceImg7, ichiYenpiggyImg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.5/konva.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stage-parent">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and provided me a great explanation! It was beneficial you showed me step by step. Thanks again!